# Play framework combining two Play application into one

Tags: java, join, playframework-2.0

I have two application written in playframework.
I would like to join one to another.
I have one database, and I would like to share my login classes between thems.
Applications have difrent names used for classes, methods, variables.

How can I achive it?
Should I create jar version and try to join them.
Or Should I move code from one app to another with new package name like application name
But what about shared views or main controller and configuration files

Please give me some advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One project make as sub-project of another one.
See this link:

```
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/SBTSubProjects
```

Comment: Can You help me with this? Here is new issue post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25746065/play-sbt-subprojects-routes-shopping-routes5-object-application-is-not-a-memb