# Play sbt subProjects routes: shopping.routes:5: object Application is not a member of package controllers.shopping

Tags: playframework, sbt, subproject

Please give me some advice.
I am following this:
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/SBTSubProjects

What I am doing wrong? I have error with sub project routes:

```
shopping.routes:5: object Application is not a member of package controllers.shopping
```

My shopping.routes:

```
GET /index                  controllers.shopping.Application.index()
GET /assets/*file           controllers.shopping.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

My shopping.controllers.Application class:

```
package controllers.shopping

import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._
import views.html._

public Class Application extends Controller {

  public Result index() {
    return ok("shopping");
  }
}
```

my main build.sbt file:

```
import play.Project._
name := "svp"


version := "2.0.0_(20140725)"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc, 
  javaJpa, 
  "org.hibernate" % "hibernate-entitymanager" % "3.6.9.Final",
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.27",
  "org.mindrot" % "jbcrypt" % "0.3m",
  cache
  )

playJavaSettings

lazy val shopping = project.in(file("modules/shopping"))

lazy val main = project.in(file(".")).dependsOn(shopping).aggregate(shopping)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've missed one folder in structure: folder "app"
so it should be:
/modules/shopping/app/controllers/Application.java

but I had instead of it:
/modules/shopping/controllers/Application.java

So I am closing :D